# Where are the Source Scaling Options in Adobe Media Encoder CS6?

Tags: encoding, adobe-media-encoder, export

In **Adobe Media encoder CC**, the Settings in the drop-down menu have a *Match Source* option that will preserve the pixel size of the file.

[image]

In this *[Adobe Help article](https://helpx.adobe.com/media-encoder/using/whats-new-ame-cs6.html)*, the authors of the page state that **Adobe Media Encoder CS6** can let the user chose "Match Source" in an "**Output**" panel.

[image]

I have seen this panel in the **Export** window of **Premiere Pro** before, but my version of **Adobe Media Encoder** doesn't seem to have this panel:

[image]

When I add projects to **Adobe Media Encoder**, they show up in the **Queue** panel, and the settings are in the top right **Preset Browser** panel. None of them has a "Match Source" option.

***If I am directly adding video files to the Encoder, which isn't in one of the preset pixel sizes, how do I encode it properly in Adobe Media Encoder CS6?***

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the h.264 match source settings preset, you'll find it in the **Preset Browser** under **System Presets > Broadcast > H.264**

[image: preset browser]

If you have another preset that you want to use, or if you're wanting to customise one, then if you look at the presets in the queue item you'll see that you can click on the name of the preset to edit the settings—note the blue line when you hover.

[image: preset name]

Once you do that the familiar export settings window will appear, with the great big **Match Source** button.

[image]

Comment: [Here are the options](https://imgur.com/228TXra) in the H.264 section of the Broadcast presets in CS6. All of them seem to change the pixel size. I clicked one of them at random, "Vimeo HD 720p 25" after dropping a 632 x 488 video, and the preset changed aspect ratio to 1280 x 720 (black bars on each side). "Change output size to match source" [is greyed out in the Source Scaling menu of the Export Settings](https://imgur.com/382xmLH). No "Match Source" in this window [anywhere](https://imgur.com/ujK74fE) either.

Comment: Hmm, that's an old version of AME. Why not just manually match the source pixel dimensions? You can then save that as a preset if you need to.

Comment: Yes, it’s a question about CS6 (see title of the question ). I have several computers recent and old, and I’d rather not have to input pixel size manually if I can avoid it. It says on Adobe Help for this version that it can be done... so it should be doable...